# Mosby & EventBus

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus, mosby

I am trying to develop an app using Mosby and EventBus. First event I want to have is after user login, creating a sticky event so every screen can access Login info at all times.

Based off the Mosby mail sample, I have a BasePresenter like this:

```
public abstract class EventBusPresenter<V extends MvpView> extends MvpBasePresenter<V> {


    private static final java.lang.String TAG = tag(EventBusPresenter.class);
    @Inject
    protected EventBus mEventBus;


    LoginSuccessfulEvent userInfo;

    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onLoginSuccessful(LoginSuccessfulEvent event) {
        MCLog.i(TAG, "Received a login event!");
        userInfo = event;
        onLoginReceived(event);
    }

    protected abstract void onLoginReceived(LoginSuccessfulEvent e);

    public LoginSuccessfulEvent getUserInfo(){
        return userInfo;
    }


    @Override
    public void attachView(V view) {
        super.attachView(view);
        mEventBus.register(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void detachView(boolean retainInstance) {
        super.detachView(retainInstance);
        mEventBus.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

When the user logins I use this code:

```
public void doLogin(String username, String password) {
    if (isViewAttached()) {
        getView().showLoading();
    }

    cancelSubscription();
    mSubscriber = new Subscriber<AuthenticationResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getView().loginSuccessful();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getView().showLoginError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse) {
            User user = authenticationResponse.getUser();
            MCLog.w(TAG, String.format("Login was successful with user: %s", user) );
            mEventBus.postSticky(new LoginSuccessfulEvent(user, authenticationResponse.getToken()));
            String token = authenticationResponse.getToken();
            MCLog.i(TAG, String.format("Token obtained = %s", token));
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(PreferenceKeys.TOKEN_KEY, token).apply();


        }
    };
```

My idea is that for every screen, as soon as its loaded it can retrieve the UserInfo through the EventBus subscription.

The issue is -- this event arrives too son. As per mosby's own BaseFragment class I do this:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> extends MvpFragment<V, P> {

    private Unbinder mUnbinder;

    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract int getLayoutRes();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(getLayoutRes(), container, false);
    }


    @Override public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inject();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @Override public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }

    /**
     * Inject dependencies
     */
    protected void inject() {

    }


}
```

This means that injection arrives before the views are created, so whenever I try to respond to a LoginEvent being received, the UI elements that need updating are not there anymore.

How can I achieve this? Is this even the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do `mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` either in `onCreateView()` or if you prefer to do that in `onViewCreated()` the call `mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` before calling `super.onViewCreated()`.

Btw. Using an EventBus for that sounds painful. Why not simply having a class like `UserMananger` where you can get the current authenticated user or null if user is not authenticated. Also, since you are using RxJava it would make sense to include the `UserManager` in your RxJava chain / stream on each screen.

Comment: Thanks, can you expand on the last part? Including UserManager in my RxJava chain? I did eventually create a UserManager so Im curious about this.